# CameraX When I press Take Photo button, cant enter OnImageSavedCallback

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, camera, android-camerax

I tried to check issue with breakpoints but at this: "object : OnImageSavedCallback{
" line, debugger can't go further and just exits the function without any error. I hope someone can show me the part that I'm missing.

I also already added the permission requests to AndroidManifest.xml for writing and reading media on storage.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var  binding: ActivityMainBinding

private var imageCapture:ImageCapture? = null
private lateinit var outputDirectory: File

private lateinit var  cameraExecutor:ExecutorService

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    outputDirectory = getOutputDirectory()
    cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

    if(allPermissionGranted()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Camera Permissions are Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        startCamera()
    }
    else
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this, Constants.REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS,
            Constants.REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS
        )
    }

    binding.btnTakePhoto.setOnClickListener {
        takePhoto()
    }


}

private  fun getOutputDirectory(): File{
    val mediaDir = externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let { mFile ->
        File(mFile, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply {
            mkdirs()
        }
    }

    return  if(mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists())
        mediaDir else filesDir
}

private fun takePhoto(){
    val imageCapture = imageCapture?: return

    val photoFile = File(
        outputDirectory,
        SimpleDateFormat(Constants.FILE_NAME_FORMAT,
            Locale.getDefault()).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg")

    val outputOption = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

    imageCapture.takePicture(
        outputOption, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
        object : OnImageSavedCallback{
            override fun onImageSaved(outputFileResults: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                val savedUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
                val msg = "Photo Saved"

                Toast.makeText(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    "$msg $savedUri",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            }

            override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                Log.e(Constants.TAG, "onError: ${exception.message}",exception)
            }
        }
    )
}
private fun startCamera(){
    val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

    cameraProviderFuture.addListener({

        val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

        val preview = Preview.Builder().build().also {
            mPreview->
            mPreview.setSurfaceProvider(
                binding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider
            )
        }
        imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder().build()

        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

        try{
            cameraProvider.unbindAll()
            cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture
            )

        }
        catch (e: Exception){
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "startCamera Fail:", e)
        }
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
}

@SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    if(requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS){
        if(allPermissionGranted()){
            startCamera()
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions Not Granted by User", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            finish()
        }
    }
}

private  fun allPermissionGranted() =
    Constants.REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all{
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            baseContext, it
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    cameraExecutor.shutdown()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Emirhan.

I believe the error is in "outputOption".
Switch to this code and try to run the application and click the button.

Another thing, when trying to run the program and your app closes you can use the "Debug" to see which line of code is giving problem.

I hope it worked out, hug.

...

val outputFilesOption = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

```
        imageCapture.takePicture(
            outputFilesOption,getMainExecutor(this),
            object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
```

...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But still having same issue. And about debuging, problem doesn't close actaully, just exits from the function and continues  without any error log on the   console etc.